# Changing data type with pandas on read_excel

Tags: python, pandas, types

I'm looking for some help as I'm actually quite new to pandas (and python).
I'm facing a data type conversion problem with some datas.

As you can see (and try), I'm trying to tell pandas that I want it to read the "DEP" data column as a string (because I want to keep the data unchanged)

```
>>> df = pd.read_excel("http://www2.impots.gouv.fr/documentation/statistiques/ircom2003/dep/060.xls", 0, skiprows=23, na_values="n.d.")
>>> df.dtypes
Unnamed: 0                                                  float64
DEP                                                         float64
Commune                                                     float64
...

>>> df["DEP"] = df["DEP"].astype(str)

>>> df.dtypes
Unnamed: 0                                                  float64
DEP                                                          object
Commune                                                     float64
.....

>>> df["DEP"][5]
'60.0'
```

You can download the excel file if you want, but the input data look like this : (I've added the slash between column names)

```
DEP / Commune   / Libellé de la commune
060 001 AIGLUN
060 002 AMIRAT
```

In this case, I would like to simply keep the data "060" and "001" as strings.
I'm using python 3.4 and pandas 0.16

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: There was a ticket for this function. See https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5891.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert to string with formatting:

```
df["DEPS"]=df["DEPS"].map(lambda x:'{0:03d}'.format(int(x)))
```

convert to int to drop decimal place and convert int to string with 3 digits.

edit: Just to elaborate, excel stores numbers as floats, and not strings like in a csv file. When reading .csv files, you can specify column "dtype"s

Comment: worth noting that `dtypes` option is not available for `pd.read_excel()`

Comment: It is now (as of pandas 0.20).

Answer (score 1):

There is another possibility. I must admit it's a little bit scrapy, but I tested successfully.

You need to create a new class:

```
class NewType():
   def __init__(self, sValue=""):
        self.strValue = sValue

   def __str__(self):
        return self.strValue
```

then define a convert function:

```
def convert(value):
    return NewType(value)
```

in your function (where you want to read_excel), do the following, assuming you have 28 columns to read:

```
import pandas as pd
converters = dict()
for i  in range(0,28,1):
    converters[i] = convert
dataframe = pd.read_excel(path_to_file, sheet_name, 0, None, 0, None, 27, False, None, "", None, False, None, converters)
dataframe = dataframe.transpose()
dataDict = dataframe.to_dict() 
newDict= OrderedDict()
for dataLine in dataDict.values():
    for field in dataLine.keys():
        dataLine[field] = str(dataLine[field])
    #do something with dataLine
```

At the end you have something identical to CSV.DictReader if you had the data formatted in CSV